# while generating heap dump using jprofiler13.0.7 version for linux attaching not supported operation error thrown

Tags: java, jprofiler

```
sudo -u root bin/jpdump --pid=16966     --file=/mnt/c/javaProfiler/jprofilerCentOs/dump
```

> Creating heap dump file /mnt/c/javaProfiler/jprofilerCentOs/dump.hprof
> ... ERROR: Attaching is not supported: could not open socket
> /proc/16966/root/tmp/.java_pid16966

Both the `Java` application and `JProfiler` are running in the same machine.

as per documentation this should generate the heap dump file. The requirement is to generate the heap dump from production environment where only `JRE` is present. `JDK` is not available. And cant use the normal `GUI` interface in the `Linux` or `CentOS` machines.

Comment: Is PID 16966 running as root or as another user?